# Can't Set Property's Property

Tags: vb.net, properties, set, setter

I am having trouble with, as I said, setting a property's property.  Let's say I have a class that represents a transaction.  In my class I have a property that represents another class, such as this:

```
Public Class PersonRecord

    _myPerson = new Person()

    Public Property MyPerson as Person
    Get
        _myPerson = Person.GetAppropriatePerson(Me.PersonID)

        return _myPerson
    End Get

    Set
        _myPerson = value
    End Set
    End Property
```

So I essentially have a property that has a get filter that gets the appropriate person.  The problem is that when I want to set the Person's info through the property, VB seems to ignore that I even did it, such as this:

```
Me.myPersonRecord.Person.Name = "Some Name"
```

But when I put a watch on this, after setting the property, my value does not change.  I am puzzled by this behavior.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you do a get `.MyPerson`, the function `Person.GetAppropriatePerson` gets called.

I do not know the implementation of that function, but I would guess that it returns a new Person object every time that it is called.

You change the Name of one Person instance. The next time you call `.MyPerson`, another Person instance gets returned.

Depending on how this is supposed to work, you could do a few things, for instance:

- Call `GetAppropriatePerson` in the constructor (if personid is known at that time). Assign the return value to `_myPerson`, and make the `MyPerson` property read-only.
- Or initialize `_myPerson` to `null`, then in the `MyPerson` getter have a `if _myPerson == null Then _myPerson = GetAppropriatePerson etc.`

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  I don't see any way around this, though, unless I remove the getter and just use a function every time I want to get the property's appropriate customer name.

Comment: How about option two above? See the answer by @Dan F for a full example of what your MyPerson property should look like.

Comment: Hey, that worked!  I can't believe I didn't think to do the simple if statement to check for a null.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's a copy n paste error, but you appear to be overwriting `_myPerson` every time in the Get part of the property. That would more than likely cause your "Some Name" to get overwritten :-)

**edit** *do'h, codeape says the same thing seconds before me :-)*

A common pattern for lazy initialisation of properties like this is to do something like the following, which checks if the object is null before overwriting it.

```
Public Property MyPerson as Person
Get
    If _myPerson Is Nothing Then
        _myPerson = Person.GetAppropriatePerson(Me.PersonID)
    End If
    return _myPerson
End Get
```

You'd have to change your `_myPerson` initialisation to be a straight `dim _myPerson as Person`, rather than `dim _myPerson as New Person()` too

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the help, but codeape just got there first ;)  However, it is reassuring that I am using a pattern that I didn't even realize.  I always wondered how lazy initialization was used.

Answer (score 1):

It must be getting changed by this line:
_myPerson = Person.GetAppropriatePerson(Me.PersonID)

step through you code...